# Pivot longer into 3 columns

Tags: r, date, pivot-table

I have a df with 1000+ columns for dates (from 2017-01-01 to 2020-01-01), and rows for 500+ providers, filled with the daily sales per provider.
I would like to have it in 3 rows (provider, date and daily sales), but can't understand the way pivot_longer works for a 2+ columns output.

What I have:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  Provider  | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-04 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Nestle     |         12 |         10 |          8 |         12 |
| Heineken   |          - |          3 |          1 |          3 |
| Hagen Dazs |          5 |          - |          - |          2 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Output I want:

```
|  Provider  |    Date    | Sales |
+------------+------------+-------+
| Nestle     | 2017-01-01 |    12 |
| Nestle     | 2017-01-02 |     8 |
| Nestle     | 2017-01-03 |    10 |
| Nestle     | 2017-01-04 |    12 |
| Heineken   | 2017-01-02 |     3 |
| Heineken   | 2017-01-03 |     1 |
| Heineken   | 2017-01-04 |     3 |
| Hagen Dazs | 2017-01-01 |     5 |
| Hagen Dazs | 2017-01-04 |     2 |
+------------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: I think `pivot_longer(df, -1)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Technically the great suggestion from **@AllanCameron** does the job. You only need to polish it adding a filter for `-` and formating the variable as numeric if needed:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% pivot_longer(-Provider) %>%
  filter(value!='-') %>% mutate(value=as.numeric(value))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  Provider   name       value
  <chr>      <chr>      <dbl>
1 Nestle     2017-01-01    12
2 Nestle     2017-01-02    10
3 Nestle     2017-01-03     8
4 Nestle     2017-01-04    12
5 Heineken   2017-01-02     3
6 Heineken   2017-01-03     1
7 Heineken   2017-01-04     3
8 Hagen Dazs 2017-01-01     5
9 Hagen Dazs 2017-01-04     2
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Provider = c("Nestle", "Heineken", "Hagen Dazs"
), `2017-01-01` = c("12", "-", "5"), `2017-01-02` = c("10", "3", 
"-"), `2017-01-03` = c("8", "1", "-"), `2017-01-04` = c("12", 
"3", "2")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `melt`

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    melt(id.var = 'Provider') %>% 
    mutate(value = replace(value, value == '-', NA)) %>% 
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Provider = c("Nestle", "Heineken", "Hagen Dazs"
), `2017-01-01` = c("12", "-", "5"), `2017-01-02` = c("10", "3", 
"-"), `2017-01-03` = c("8", "1", "-"), `2017-01-04` = c("12", 
"3", "2")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```